# Why does this SQL script work as it does?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm pulling email address records from a table in SQL Server 2005, and want to build a single string to use as the `@recipients` list with `sp_send_dbmail`. The table has a field called EmailAddress and there are 10 records in the table.

I'm doing this:

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @email = ISNULL(@email + '; ', '') + EmailAddress
FROM
    accounts
```

Now @email has a semi-delimited list of 10 email address from the accounts table.

My questions is why/how does this work? Why doesn't @email only have the last email address in the table?

Comment: I don't know, but this is a very good question.  I can't wait to see the answers.

Comment: Used this today for creating a string of fields for a pivot command.  Awesome. Glad I had it bookmarked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for each row you concatentate the current value of `@email` with the next result in `EmailAddress`.  String concatenation is just like calling a function, in that it must evaluate the result for each row in sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have 3 addresses:

```
a@b.c
b@b.c
c@b.c
```

For the first row, `@email` is `NULL`, so it becomes `"" + "a@b.c"`, so `"a@b.c"`.

For the second row, `@email` becomes `"a@b.c" + "; " + "b@b.c"`, so `"a@b.c; b@b.c"`.

For the last row, `@email` becomes `"a@b.c; b@b.c" + "; " + "c@b.c"`, so `"a@b.c; b@b.c; c@b.c"`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the concatenation expression is evaluated once per row.

Comment: Your answer is concise and, in my mind, answers the question most succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT isn't selecting rows - for display - it's repeatedly concatenating an expression to the same variable. So at the end, all you have left to show is the variable.

Presumably you find that out with another line in the batch file, e.g. "SELECT @email"

Think:

result = "" + name1
result = result + name2
result = result + name3
etc.

Possibly you're thinking that SELECT variable = expression is a combination assignment and SELECT; but it's really just an assignment. In any case, @email isn't reinitialized for each row.